# Store Hash and/or Encryption salts in database

Tags: hash, salt

I am doing a custom login for practice purposes, and i am wondering what would be the logical way to save the hashed password and the salts.

- Salt/Hash operations are using Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.

As for now, it is like this:

- The user registers, the password is encrypted with a random salt (which is saved to the database) and hashed with a hard-coded salt with 10000 iterations.

As the iterations can be raised in time due to computational improvements, i am saving the Hash iterations (the Encryption iterations are hard-coded) them on the database.

I would like opinions on how safe is a hard-coded hash salt, or if i should make it random and add the hash salt to the database too.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second salt if the password is already hashed with a first random salt?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you use a static string as a salt for example,  `"thisisstaticand10000characterslong"`. Use the password inside this `( $salt1.$post['password'].$salt2)`.  Then hash it with MD5. If the user wants to login than you make the same method to check if the password entered by the user is correct.

```
if(md5(($salt1.$_POST['password'].$salt2) == $password)
{ 
    /* Your code */
}
```

Comment: Never use a cryptographic hash to store user set passwords - it is far too fast. See the linked post (user bcrypt, pbkdf2 or scrypt instead).